# Creating a Web UI for StrongLoop build & deploy processes?

Tags: node.js, user-interface, loopbackjs, strongloop

I want to build web ui for **StrongLoop**. It would let a user build and deploy process with that UI like StrongLoop Arc.

There are simple node applications(Web Services) without created with StrongLoop tools. Need to deploy these applications via web ui. Solution in my mind is some server-side processes, listed steps below:

1. Upload zip folder(node application) to server
2. Extract zip and build to tar.gz by shell command (slc build) through `node.js child_process API`
3. Deploy tar.gz file to relevant StrongLoop host by shell command(slc deploy..) through API which is mentioned on previous step.

I wonder is there any alternative way to deploy node application(without created with StrongLoop tools) to StrongLoop host via web ui using some StrongLoop API?

I have looked API could not find specific solution.

Answer (score 2):

What you require is a **CDP** (*Continuous delivery pipeline*) setup, there seem to be ***many ways*** in which you can achieve this (easiest way is using [**Codeship**](http://codeship.com/) or ***similar platforms***), but if you want to know how it works it requires a bit of ***orchestration tools*** to help you. To describe the steps I'll be using the following tools:

- **Docker** ([what is docker?](https://www.docker.com/what-docker))
- **Ansible** ([Use Cases](https://www.ansible.com/use-cases-overview) and [How it works?](https://www.ansible.com/how-ansible-works))
- **Jenkins** ([What is it and Why to use it?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-Jenkins-When-and-why-is-it-used))

> *"There are many other combination of tools that you can look at, but this should give you an idea"*

Now that we have the tools, I'll try to describe the deployment pipeline with a very basic use-case.

### **Step I** "*Ideally*" - **Creating a docker image for your nodejs application.**

What generally everyone suggests is that you create a docker image of your application. Then save this image on **docker-hub**. How this will help you is that, now your nodejs application is contained inside a ***docker image*** which makes it independent of the Host and can be deployed anywhere you want.
To create this image all you need to do is create a **Dockerfile**, which is described in the in the [link](https://www.docker.com/what-docker) I've shared.

### **Step II** "*Ideally*" - Creating an Ansible playbook to mimic the setup steps of your application.

Ansible playbooks are basically used to ***automate every manual process*** that you would need to do in order to **setup**-**deploy**-**run** your application. This decreases the need to run even trivial tasks like "***slc build***".

### Step III "*Ideally*" - This is where we get to the UI stuff

By using Jenkins, you are given a UI which will help you configure tasks that can be combined with **Github** hooks and trigger the deployment as soon as you make a commit. This is explained in more details in the [link](https://www.quora.com/What-is-Jenkins-When-and-why-is-it-used) shared.

So to summarize, This is what goes on at back to some extent, in order to automate the build and deployment of your application **using UI**. I hope ***this serves as a good starting point*** to achieve your requirements, and also in case you want skip these steps in the start, you could always go with [**Codeship**](http://codeship.com/) or similar other tools to help you with the steps that you've mentioned.